# TestNG xml + Linux OS + Jenkins --> Nothing happening

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

Folder structure: 
[image]

Now my Jenkins are hosted on a Linux machine. So in my base file where the drivers will be picked up based on OS. 
Below is the code:

```
//Function to instantiate the WebDriver instance based on the Browser selected for Linux
public WebDriver driverInsLinux(){
    setbaseURL();

    try {
        switch(getBrowser()){

        case "Chrome":
            System.out.println("Inside Linux chrome driver function");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Linux/Drivers/chromedriver");
            System.out.println("driver launch successful");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get(baseurl);
            break;

            case "Internet Explorer":
                System.setProperty("webdriver.internetexplorer.driver", "./Linux/Drivers/internetexplorerdriver.exe");
                driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            case "Firefox":
                driver=new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
                default:
                    //new PascalBaseClass();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.get(baseurl);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1366, 768));
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;
}

    //Function to instantiate the WebDriver based on the OS
public WebDriver driverIns(){

    //driver =driverInsWindows();

    switch (getOSName()) {

    case "Windows": driver =driverInsWindows();
        break;
    case "Linux" : driver =driverInsLinux();
        break;
    case "MAC" : driver =driverInsMac();
        break;

    }
    return driver;

}
        //Function to get the OS Name
public String getOSName(){

        oSName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if(oSName.contains("Windows"))
        oSName= "Windows";
    System.out.println(oSName);
    return oSName;

}
```

Now the LoginPage.java

```
public class LoginPage extends Base{

/*Members of the current Test Class. The number varies from script
to script depending on the variables and verifications required*/
public WebDriver driver;
private String currentSitePath;
private String testCaseName=getClass().getName().substring(10); 
ExtentTest parentTest;


//Function to Navigate to a particular URL inside CC
public void navigateToURL(WebDriver driver){
    siteURL="";
    this.driver.navigate().to(baseurl+siteURL);
    }


@Test // Main Test Flow for the Script
public void executeScript() throws IOException{

    System.out.println("*******************");
    System.out.println("launching chrome browser");

    parentTest= ReportGenerator.initializeParentTest(getClass().getName().substring(10),"Testing Login Page");

    //Test Case Author assignment in Reports 
    ReportGenerator.assignAuthor(parentTest,"Garima");

    //Setting up Browser Instance
    this.driver=driverIns();

    //Navigating to the required page in CC
    navigateToURL(this.driver);
```

Jenkins console output:

```
+ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)
+ uname -a
Linux jenkins2.spikes.eng 2.6.32-754.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 19 21:26:04 
UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
+ id
uid=498(jenkins) gid=498(jenkins) groups=498(jenkins) 
context=system_u:system_r:unconfined_java_t:s0
+ cd CC_Regression
+ chmod -R 777 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression
  + export 
 'CLASSPATH=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/bin: 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/*'
 + 
 CLASSPATH='/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/bin: 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/*'
 + java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
 [TestNG] Running:
  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/testng.xml

 *******************
 launching chrome browser

 ===============================================
 Suite
 Total tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
 Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
 ===============================================

 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Note: 
1) for Linux drivers: I have download the file:chromedriver_linux64 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.40/

Once download is done, extracted the file and placed it in Linx/Drivers folder

2) Tried multpile syso at different steps in above functions.. But seems like post System.out.println("launching chrome browser");  it is breaking.

Comment: Do you have chrome browser installed on your Linux machine? Is it a physical machine or vm? Which Linux distribution is it? Can you also attach the stack trace of your given error?

Comment: how to get stack trace of error.. sorry but I am new to Jenkis .

Comment: Before the line driver=new ChromeDriver(); put system.out.println("before initilazing driver"); and after the line put system.out.println("after initilazing driver"); and try again. And please answer the rest of my questions above.

Comment: System.out.println("*******************");
  System.out.println("launching chrome browser");
  
  parentTest= ReportGenerator.initializeParentTest(getClass().getName().substring(10),"Testing Login Page");
  
  //Test Case Author assignment in Reports 
     ReportGenerator.assignAuthor(parentTest,"Garima");
  
  //Setting up Browser Instance
  System.out.println("report generator done");
  this.driver=driverIns();

Comment: and even not getting "report generator done" text in console. Regarding OS: Its CentOS. for physical or VM I need to check other team. As I had only Jenkins url. Will check and revert

Comment: Please post the code of the method ReportGenerator.initializeParentTest

Comment: public static ExtentTest initializeParentTest(String testName,String description){
  
  
  return report.startTest(testName, description);
 }
 //Function to assign author to the Parent Test
 public static void assignAuthor(ExtentTest parentTest,String authorName){
  
  parentTest.assignAuthor(authorName);
 }

Comment: What happens if you run this test locally?

Comment: With eclipse of Win7/Win10 and Mac code is working perfectly.

Comment: My advice, try to run it with java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml locally on Linux machine, then it would ease your debugging

Comment: ok let me try to get one linux machine

Comment: answers to your questions: 1) VM 2) Centos 6 3) Chrome browser not installed

Comment: Please be aware:      driver=new ChromeDriver() is intended to create local instance of chrome driver. If the machine which runs the code does not have the chrome browser installed, the driver would fail to start a session. So anyways this code currently would not succeed on current workflow.

Comment: so can a headless chrome browser will be an option ?

Comment: Headless chrome is also requiring chrome browser installed.

Comment: Even after installing chrome on Linux.. same issue

Comment: what about the local debugging with linux?

Comment: will be able to comment on that by tomorrow.. raised request to get a Linux machine

Comment: Ok waiting for your update