# Headless driver

Tags: selenium, headless-browser

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //System.out.println(JavaUtils.getMonthOldDate());
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Exception in console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DISMISS_AND_NOTIFY
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:225)
at testCases.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Downloaded jar's from : https://jar-download.com/?search_box=selenium-htmlunit-driver

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: @garimagarg Any reason to use `BrowserVersion.CHROME`?

Comment: I specifically wanted to run on headless chrome version

Comment: Well, you got an accepted answer. Carry on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code , and I am not getting any error.  Output was **Google**

Maybe you will have to download latest chrome driver , chrome browser version and Selenium.

My config :

**Chrome:**   `Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
**Selenium**  `3.12.0 (you can go for 3.13.0 also)`
**Chrome driver** : `version 2.40`

Download links : [Chrome_driver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.40/)
[Selenium 3.13.0](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
Browser you can just upgrade.

Comment: there is no need for Chrome driver, just simple htmlunit-driver, probably issue with drivers.

Comment: could be. even If he/she does , I do not see any harm. BTW thanks for mentioning.

Comment: used selenium 2.53 . chrome version 68.0.3440.59

Comment: use selenium 3.13.0 with chrome 68.0.344 , You can follow download link in my answer.

Comment: Use latest drivers. I've managed to get title. Probably some issues with environment, as @cruisepandey mantioned try using different driver, 2.53 is a bit old now

Comment: Just one question: is it compulsory to have chrome installed on system if i give new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME)

Comment: Yes it is needed, can you update me also if browser is not present then what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Hey.. Uninstalled chrome from my Win7 system. And ran above code.. and guess what... It worked :D

Comment: :) , Even I did not check this scenario. Thanks for update. Cheers !

Comment: hopefully headless driver will solve my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320801/testng-xml-linux-os-jenkins-nothing-happening?noredirect=1#comment89686112_51320801 too .. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I've tried this as simple code example and its working for me:

```
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
   import org.testng.Assert;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class TestHtmlHeadless {

        @Test
        public void runHtmlHeadless() {
            String URl = "http://checkip.dyndns.com/";

            HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
            driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

            Assert.assertTrue(!isEmpty(driver), "Driver should not be empty!");

            driver.get(URl);

            System.err.println("Open Page: " + URl);

            String ip = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).getText();
            System.out.println("Debug: " + ip);

            Assert.assertTrue(!isEmpty(ip));
        }



        public static boolean isEmpty(Object val) {
            if (val == null) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

try using maven or gradle to fetch, this bellow is maven pom.xml file and use it in maven nature, and it would work:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Result:**

[image]

or download html-driver here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases

Comment: tried htmlunit-driver-2.31.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar too from github but same issue.